# TI CC2541 no BLE GATT communication

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, microcontroller

I am working on a project with **TI CC2541 MCU** and having major issues with BLE communication with Android.

I was wondering what Android app or Windows software can I use to read and write to GATT of CC2541 (I don't have CC 2540 dongle)? I have been trying with BLE SensorTag, Sensortag and BlueExplorer on Google Play. The first two seems to be capable of only reading it, while BlueExplorer outputs error each time I try to change any value.

I have also tried to code my own Android app, but no success with GATT. Is there a working sample code available anywhere to help with testing?

Please kindly check the screenshots of the apps attached in this [**link**](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18516025/ble%20screeshots.zip)  (I cannot post them as images here)

Comment: What firmware are you using on CC2541?

Comment: I am using the firmware from [this project](http://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-00096). The mobile phone app is however not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in documentation page from the [link](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu195a/tidu195a.pdf) (page 17) you have provided.

> When configured by a peer device, the ECG peripheral application sends
>   notification of the ECG measurement. On power up, advertising is
>   enabled and the peer device must discover and initiate a connection
>   procedure to the ECG peripheral. When the peer device configures the
>   ECG measurement for notification, a timer starts and ECG measurements
>   are sent periodically. In addition to ECG measurement, the peer device
>   can read the number of ECG channels supported (characteristic 2) and
>   the number of ECG-sample data sets per packet (characteristic 3). The
>   peer device may also discover and configure the battery service for
>   battery level-state notifications. This functionality is the same as
>   supported in Simple BLE Peripheral framework

Only characteristic that you could write is

|GATT_CLIENT_CHAR_CFG_UUID |  00:00 (2 bytes) | Write "01:00" to enable
notifications. "00:00" to
disable|

Service that you should use is  0x2D0D (ECG_SERV_UUID), which is your application service.

All other like 1800, 1801, 180a are the the services that you should not use (these are Generic Access Service, Generic Attribute Service, Device Information Service)

Hope it helps.